# Change state prop in Interface - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

I have a boolean in an Interface. I use it to change some CSS for a sidebar.

I want a button to change the state of the prop `sidebarOpen`

Here is my attempt :

```
interface ISidebar {
  logout?: boolean;
  sidebarOpen?: boolean;
}

class Sidebar extends Component<ISidebar> {
  render() {
    const handleSidebar = () => {
      this.props.sidebarOpen ? this.props.sidebarOpen(false) : this.props.sidebarOpen(true);
    };

 return (
   [...]
     <button onClick={handleSidebar} className="buttonSideBar">-</button>
   [...]
```

This `handleSidebar` method does not work. I have a typescript error : `Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.`

Any idea how I can make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface signature (more specifically the `sidebarOpen? boolean;` part) says that the `sidebarOpen` prop is an optional boolean value (i.e. it is either `true`, `false`, or `undefined`).

A boolean value is not a function.

Then in your `const handleSidebar` function, you try to call `this.props.sidebarOpen` as a function, with a boolean value.

More specifically, you try to use it as both a boolean value *and* a function.

You use it as a boolean value when you do the `this.props.sidebarOpen ? ... : ...` statement. Then, within each of those branches, you try to call the same prop *as a function*. If that prop is a boolean value, it cannot be called as a function.

My guess is that you need some additional prop that is a function that will open the sidebar.

It might look something like this:

```
interface ISidebar {
    logout?: boolean;
    sidebarOpen?: boolean;
    openSidebar: (a: boolean) => void;
}
```

...and then later in the code:

```
this.props.sidebarOpen ? this.props.openSidebar(false) : this.props.openSidebar(true);
```

I do not know the specifics of your particular program, but I know that you cannot use the same prop as both a boolean value for checking state *and* a function at the same time.